# I am trying to use the wordpress rest api but data does not display

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I am just starting with the Wordpress rest API and I am trying to integrate it into a mobile app. I have imported jquery and the url is good and displays the data in a browser.

Here is my code so far, I can not get the data to display

```
<body>

    <script>
   $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://wpecom.robbotdev.com/blog/wp-json/' + 'wp/v2/posts',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
    // do something with the data here
        $.each(data, function(index, value) {

  $('ul.topcoat-list').append('<li class="topcoat-list__item">' +
    '<img src="'+value.featured_image.attachment_meta.sizes.medium.url+'" /><br>' +
    '<h3>'+value.title+'</h3>' +
    '<p>'+value.content+'</p></li>');

});
    }
});

    </script>

    <li class="topcoat-list__item">
<img src="http://url.com/featured/image.png" /><br>
<h3>Title</h3>
<p>Post excerpt</p>
</li>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I use AJAX for this, I don't use `type` or `dataType`.  Try removing those two and see if it works out!  Also, are there any JS errors in your console?  Maybe the AJAX is running before the `ul.topcoat-list` is even created.  Maybe put your AJAX call inside a `jQuery( document ).ready( function()`, or move it below the HTML before the `</body>`.

Comment: no good man, I tried but still the same result. i am not seeing any error in the console either

Comment: Do a console.log() to see what data is coming back, if any.  Do you see the AJAX call in the console?  It should show there.  If not, your AJAX is probably not even running.  Add a failure function to see if that gets triggered... put the whole thing in a function and run that function in a document.ready...

Comment: i got the raw json data to show up in the console after removing all the filters

Comment: So does that mean you are all set?  You can now access all values inside the JSON?

Comment: I still can not get them to display to html but that is another question